# jQuery - Animate object that has been given a random id

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, random

I want to know how I can animate an object that I have assigned a random ID to.

Basically I have a button that creates an "house" in a container. And when I click to create the house, it will append to my container with a random ID and a set CLASS:

```
$('.Container').append('<div id="'+iRandomId+'" class="House" title="'+sName+'"></div>');
```

The Random ID I get like this:

```
var iRandomId = GetRandomNumber(999999, 99999999999);
oObject.setId(iRandomId);

function GetRandomNumber(iMinNumber, iMaxNumber)
{
return  Math.floor(Math.random()* iMaxNumber +iMinNumber);      
}
```

**Animation:** I can easily animate the object by calling the class. But if I create more than one House they will of course all animate..

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('.House').effect('bounce');
}, 0, function(){
```

The annimation is triggered when another object is dragged on top of my house (which is droppable). What I need for my jQuery is to somehow check the ID of the specific house that the object is dragged on to. And then only animate that house.

Comment: not sure if it matters but your random number generator doesn't generate between iMinNumber and iMaxNumber

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with the question but : why the random id ? Does not seem necessary and you may encounter twice the same id. Well, you're playing with probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming jQuery UI's `droppable` or similar, it triggers a `drop` event with `this` as the droppable when the drop occurs, so within the event handler:

```
$(this).effect('bounce');
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/OWEloRO/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/OWEloRO/1/edit) (quoted inline below)

If this is the only reason you're using an `id`, you can stop using an `id`. If it isn't, then you should fix your code so it's not possible to end up with two elements with the same `id` (since it's perfectly reasonable — and random — for your function to return `42` twice in a row). The easiest way is to have a starting point and just increment by one each time you use it.

---

CSS:

```
.dropzone {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.dragme {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Drag the blue squares into the rectangles, which
will turn yellow briefly on drop.</p>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dragme"></div>
<div class="dragme"></div>
<div class="dragme"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".dropzone").droppable({
  drop: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css("background-color", "yellow");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.css("background-color", "");
    }, 500);
  }
});
$(".dragme").draggable();
```

Comment: And thus remove this random id generation, which is kinda ugly.